# how to replace broken images with url in word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have word document containing broken images with url.
I want to replace broken images with new one. I found bit of solution from earlier posts.

I came to this much.

**Edit**

I came to this after hint.

```
Sub BrokenImages2()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim StrTxt As String, HttpReq As Object, i As Long
Set HttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "^g"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne
  End With
  Do While .Find.Found
    If .Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then
      s = .Hyperlinks(1).Address
    MsgBox s
        If InStr(s, "about") = 1 Then
        s = Replace(.Hyperlinks(1).Address, "about", "HTTP")
        MsgBox s
        With Dialogs(wdDialogInsertPicture)
        .Name = s
        .Execute
        End With
        End If
    End If
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    .Find.Execute
  Loop
End With
End Sub
```

The problem with above code is it doesn't replaces the images but adds new images at selection.
Please guide me how to do this correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I wanted

```
Sub BrokenImg()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim StrTxt As String, HttpReq As Object, i As Long
Set HttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
Set rng1 = ActiveDocument.Range
With rng1
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "^g"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .Execute
  End With
  Do While .Find.Found
    Set rng2 = ActiveDocument.Range(rng1.End, ActiveDocument.Range.End)
    If .Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then
      s = .Hyperlinks(1).Address
    MsgBox s
        If InStr(s, "about") = 1 Then
        s = Replace(.Hyperlinks(1).Address, "about", "https")
        MsgBox s
        MsgBox s
            rng2.InlineShapes.AddPicture FileName:= _
        s _
        , LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True
        End If
    End If
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    .Find.Execute
    Set rng2 = Nothing
  Loop
End With
Set rng1 = Nothing
End Sub
```

Still this have one problem. Selection is required at first found. Need to work around
In above code, it works perfect if cursor point is at the first image to be found.

If cursor point is at somewhere else it find the first image, extract links, modify it but inserts image at cursor point. If there is next image in the document, it does the same but insets the image at first image found. the other problem with above code is, i don't know how to delete the original graphic if it matches the criteria.

I tried modifying above code like this.

```
Set rng2 = ActiveDocument.Range(rng1.End, ActiveDocument.Range.End)
    With rng2
        If .Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then
```

But it loops indefinitely. May be something wrong from my side as I am inexperienced.

File is at here.
https://sites.google.com/site/rtsk2015/fo/BrokenArrow.docx?attredirects=0&d=1

Comment: I'm having trouble with your problem description (language barrier) so am only able to guess, to a certain extent, what is meant... After the first FIND.EXECUTE rng1 should contain the image. rng1.Delete should remove it. Does that work correctly, as far as it goes? (One step at a time...)

Comment: I don't Understand the Language (VBA), that is the problem. I just wanted to know How do I search the ^g and make the found image as range. I think current setting of range is not proper as I have copy pasted the code from somewhere else. I will look into it.

Comment: If Find is succesful, the Range on which it was executed should contain what was found. In order to test that, you can place rng1.Select in your code then move the cursor to the following line and set a breakpoing (F9). Run the code (F5) and it should stop at the breakpoint. You can then look at what's selected.

Answer (score 0):

Your Execute statement is missing the command to perform the actual replacement. Try: .Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne

Comment: Apology for not making it clear. I actually want to replace image after if found with the link it generate. I may be wrong in understanding in what you have explained as I am novice in the field. Pleas guide me. I have edited the macro as per your request and my understanding. Is it OK?

Comment: So the code in the "Answer" works for you, as far as it goes, is that correct? I don't understand what you mean by "Selection is required at first found. Need to work around" You need to provide more information...

Comment: In above code, it works perfect if cursor point is at the first image to be found. if cursor is at somewhere else it find the first image, extract links, modify it but inserts image at cursor point. if there is next image in the document, it does the same but insets the image at first image found. the other problem with above code is, i don't know how to delete the original graphic if it matches the criteria.

Comment: Adding the wdReplaceOne, as suggested in my answer, should delete the original graphic. Please test that before proceding to other questions/issues. And don't forget that you have .Find.Execute TWICE in your code. I'm not sure what that second one is for...

Comment: I want to replace only when the found criteria are met. Adding the wdReplaceOne removes irrespective of found criteria. for duplicate .execute, even I don't know why its in there. As I have told you I am a Learner. I will Try removing the later one.